# How to update a PS3 using USB drive and the PS3UPDAT.PUP

Tags: ps3

How can I use a PS3UPDAT.PUP file downloaded from the [Playstation System Software site](http://nz.playstation.com/ps3/support/system-software/) to update my PS3?

Copying it to the root of a USB flash drive doesn't seem sufficient. Does it need to be in a particular path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to place it on your USB key in a /PS3/UPDATE folder. Then, go in `Settings | System Update` and choose `Update via storage media`.
The file should then be detected and the system updated.
You can find this information on Sony support site [here](http://us.playstation.com/support/systemupdates/ps3/pc_update/index.htm).